# Latching and Momentary Combo Switch

Tags: capacitor, switches, latch

I am looking to recreate a switch circuit I have seen on an intercom system. The switch allowed for two functions, while using one momentary switch.

When the switch was pressed and emetily released, the switch latched on. It then could be pressed and emetily released, which resulted in the switch turning off. This was useful for talking on the intercom for extended periods of time.

The second function was when the switch was held for a few seconds. If the switch was held for longer than about 1-2 seconds the switch would remain on until the button was released. In this operation the switch would act as a momentary switch, useful for saying a few words into the intercom.

I am interested in breadboarding a circuit that could accomplish this. I would like to know what I will need to get this working and how to wire it up.

-Thanks very much!

Comment: "emetily"? Immediately? If you're using a micro in your system this functionality will be easy. If not, what are you using?

Comment: Brandon please edit your post along the lines that transistor stated.If you dont use a micro it will sort out the wheat from the chaff +1